# Groovy: editing a file

Tags: groovy

I have a sample file like the following:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tt_temp_user_11
(
asdfa
)
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tt_temp_user_11
(
asdfas
)

some other text in file
```

I want to convert this file into following:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE 1
(
asdfa
)
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE 2
(
asdfas
)

some other text in file
```

So basically every TEMPORARY TABLE occurrence will have number appended to it.

So far I have the following groovy script:

```
int i = 0
new File ("C:\\Not_Modified").eachFile{file ->
        println "File name: ${file.name}"
        new File ("C:\\Not_Modified\\"+file.name).eachLine {line ->
                if (line.indexOf("TEMPORARY TABLE")>0)
                {
                    i++
                }
            }
        println "There are ${i} occurences of TEMPORARY TABLE"
    }
```

How can I change the text in the file? should I be writing to a different file?

btw, I have directory in my script because I will be working on lot of these type of files in a directory.

I should have opted perl for this task but wanted to give groovy a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm think you should write to different file, it's a good practice.
Put something like line below inside your if {} (instead of i++)

```
line = line.replaceFirst(/^(create temporary table) (.*)/, "\$1 table${++i}")
```

and then, outside of your if write line variable into outfile

BTW i'm think you better use ==~ in your if instead of indexOf

Comment: Just curious - why do you suggest ==~ instead of indexOf ? Is it faster?

Comment: I'm suggest use regexp cause in that case you can detect proper "TEMPORARY TABLE" more precisely.In other words to avoid detect words TEMPORARY TABLE in data (f.e. /TEMPORARY TABLE .* /(/ or so)

Comment: ...now you have two problems...  :)

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a little function that works kind of like File.eachLine{} works but allows editing.

You can use it like this:

```
def n=1
modifyFile("filename"){
    if(it.startsWith("CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE"))
        return "CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE " + n++
    return it // Re-inserts unmodified line"
}
```

This is pretty easy to code--whatever is returned from the closure is written out to the new file. If you want a different file, provide two filenames.

```
    /**
     * This will completely re-write a file, be careful.
     * 
     * Simple Usage:
     *
     * modifyFile("C:\whatever\whatever.txt") {
     *   if(it.contains("soil"))
     *      return null  // remove dirty word
     *   else
     *      return it
     * }
     *
     * The closure must return the line passed in to keep it in the file or alter it, any alteration
     * will be written in it's place.
     *
     * To delete an entire line instead of changing it, return null
     * To add more lines after a given line return: it + "\n" + moreLines
     *
     * Notice that you add "\n" before your additional lines and not after the last
     * one because this method will normally add one for you.
     */
    def modifyFile(srcFile, Closure c) {
        modifyFile(srcFile, srcFile, c)
    }

    def modifyFile(srcFile, destFile, Closure c={println it;return it}) {
        StringBuffer ret=new StringBuffer();
        File src=new File(srcFile)
        File dest=new File(destFile)

        src.withReader{reader->
            reader.eachLine{
                def line=c(it)
                if(line != null) {
                    ret.append(line)
                    ret.append("\n")
                }
            }
        }
        dest.delete()
        dest.write(ret.toString())
    }
}
```