# Tuning Gradle startScripts in Application Plugin

Tags: java, gradle

I using Gradle with the Application plugin.
I am trying to tune the the `startScripts` task. I don't think that the tuning demands a lot of changes, so I would like to change the standard task:

- The complete distribution includes its own JRE so I want the script to refer to that library instead of using JAVA_HOME
- If possible, remove the UNIX start script. I only need the Windows script.

If possible I prefer understanding what variables in the task to change rather rewriting the task from scratch.
My question is how to do it. Looking at the documentation I saw accessors only for `applicationName`, `classpath`, `defaultJvmOpts`, `exitEnvironmentVar`, `mainClassName`, `optsEnvironmentVar`, `outputDir`, which all look irrelevant for me.
Can you guide me to a documentation describing how to do this?

Answer (score 7):

To remove a UNIX script, you can configure the `startScripts` task as:

```
startScripts {
    doLast {
        delete unixScript
    }
}
```

As for the script content, not really sure, whether it is possible to do with the [custom script generator](https://docs.gradle.org/current/groovydoc/org/gradle/jvm/application/scripts/ScriptGenerator.html), which could be used in `startScripts` as the [WindowsStartScriptGenerator](https://docs.gradle.org/current/groovydoc/org/gradle/jvm/application/tasks/CreateStartScripts.html#setWindowsStartScriptGenerator%28org.gradle.jvm.application.scripts.ScriptGenerator%29). But any way, you are able to modify the content of the start scripts in `doLast`, just referring to it as `windowsScript.text`:

```
startScripts {
    doLast {
        windowsScript.text = windowsScript.text.replace("set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe",
                "set JAVA_EXE=../relative/path/to/java/bin/java.exe")
    }
}
```

Comment: Of all my findings this definitely is the most lightweight solution, thanks!