# How do I change unixStartScriptGenerator.template in the createStartScripts task so that distTar uses my custom template file in build.gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, software-distribution, gradle-plugin

I need to modify the start script that gradle generates for the [distTar](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html) task. I [seem to be able to set unixStartScriptGenerator.template](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v3.5.0/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/plugins/DefaultTemplateBasedStartScriptGenerator.java#L58) as shown below, but when I unpack the script from the tar my changes are not there.

This is my full `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

// to use the main method in Main, which uses Jetty
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'com.example.Main'
project.version = '2017.0.0.0'

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
}

task createStartScripts(type: CreateStartScripts) {
  // based on https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/v3.5.0/subprojects/plugins/src/main/resources/org/gradle/api/internal/plugins
  def tplName = 'unixStartScriptTemplate.txt'
  // this succeeds. I tried negating it to ensure that it runs, and it failed, so it's running.
  assert project.file(tplName).exists();
  unixStartScriptGenerator.template = project.file(tplName).newReader() as TextResource
//  windowsStartScriptGenerator.template = resources.text.fromFile('customWindowsStartScript.txt')
}


dependencies {
 // mostly elided
  compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.8.+'
  compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.8.+'
  compile 'de.bwaldvogel:log4j-systemd-journal-appender:2.2.2'

  testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '3.5'
}
```

Not that it should matter, but my template, unixStartScriptTemplate.txt, is mostly the same as [the original unixStartScript.txt](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/v3.5.0/subprojects/plugins/src/main/resources/org/gradle/api/internal/plugins), but with some extra comments and a line changing JAVACMD.

If there is a better way to set this template, please let me know.

Comment: This way you add a new task whereas you should rather hook into existing one, see: https://gist.github.com/Opalo/88be0c6c1c03061581efab84bec9f96c

Comment: @Opal, that works! make it an answer?

Comment: Great! Here you go!

Comment: I was looking for s.th. similiar and found this one: [Tuning Gradle startScripts in Application Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33646825)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way you add a new task whereas you should rather hook into existing one, try:

```
tasks.withType(CreateStartScripts) {
  def tplName = 'unixStartScriptTemplate.txt'
  assert project.file(tplName).exists()
  unixStartScriptGenerator.template = resources.text.fromFile(tplName)
}
```

Comment: Just one edit: setting the template should be ```unixStartScriptGenerator.template = ...```